# how to display symbol of currency according to country

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet below in which I would like to display the symbol of currency according to region selected in column C. If we select America, the symbol of dollar must appear before the cost in B column, like when we select Europe, the symbol of euro must appear before the cost in column B.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dlfXRcSDy7XhQmRuVa3dEmx6zjHukOlOoRp5V-Em1c0/edit#gid=0

You can use VLOOKUP or CONCATENATE whatever you want, the symbol must appear before the price.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a onEdit script for you. Try it our for yourself. I added some comment if you want to change the sheetname / column to check. Hope that this fits your needs.

1. Go to tools -> Script editor
2. Choose setNumberFormat from the dropdown and run it with the little play button. Give premission.
3. (maybee repeate 2 with the onEdit from the dropdown.)
4. Close. And now you should have a working script.

**The Script for others**

```
function onEdit(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Change sheet name to check
  const sheet = "Purchase Sheet";
  const activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const cell = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  
  // 3 = column c. So change this to you needs
  if (activeSheet == sheet && cell.getColumn() == 27){
    console.log("True");
    setNumberFormat();
  }
}


function setNumberFormat() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const cell = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  let numberFormat = "";
  
  //With this as example, you can extend to your needs.
  switch (cell.getValue()) {
    case "AMERICA":
      numberFormat = "$#,##0.00";
      break;
    case "EUROPE":
      numberFormat = "€#,##0.00";
      break;
  }
  
  cell.offset(0, -21).setNumberFormat(numberFormat);
  
}
```

Comment: Great answer ;)

Comment: it shows the app is not verified... am not familiar with script

Comment: @RemcoE33.. how can we do this to a new sheet

Comment: @Remco pls tell me what changes i have to do when i do this on my actual worksheet. in that cost will be on Col F and country will be on col AA. and the sheet name is different too

Comment: @Lizi1990 how can i help if i don't know the sheetname?